# Akka/Spray CPU usage is 100%

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have created a very basic Restful service in Spary. Locally it is all working fine.

But when I deployed it onto the server (2 core), I am seeing CPU usage at 100%.

The usage peaks to 100% for a few seconds when I try to start the application. An d when I post any request to the service end-point, the CPU usage peaks to 100% for a few minutes.

Please see the below code

```
object Boot {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 implicit val system = ActorSystem("on-spray-can")
 val service = system.actorOf(Props[AuditorServiceActor], "AuditorActor")
 val config = ConfigFactory.load()
 implicit val timeout = Timeout(120.seconds)
 IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(service, config.getString("http.interface"),  config.getInt("http.port"))
  }
}


class AuditorServiceActor extends Actor with AuditorService {
 def actorRefFactory = context
 def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}
```

Comment: You should post the contents of `myRoute` since it presumably contains much of the logic, where the problem could lie.